# From a uniform integer random variable on $[1,5]$, generate a uniform integer random variable on $[1,7]$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Let $X$ be a uniform integer random variable on $[1,5]$. Using $X$, generate a uniform integer random variable on $[1,7]$. You may draw $X$ as many times you want. Or just any way you can think of.

Comment: I don't see a good way if are to draw from $X$ once (although that doesn't mean there isn't one). We can draw from $X$ twice, that would give you a lot of ways to map $25$ values of $(X,Y) \in [1,5]$ to $Z \in [1,7]$...

Comment: $$(X-1)\times\frac32 + 1 $$

Comment: @Math1000 that works only if $X$ is continuous. In my case, $X$ is integer.

Comment: Ah I missed that detail.

Comment: This is **obviously** impossible since $\#\{y\mid P(g(X)=y)\ne0\}\leqslant\#\{x\mid P(X=x)\ne0\}$ for every transformation $g$.

Comment: @Did: Actually I'm not restricting to just one draw of $X$. You can draw twice, for example as gt989b did. Probably I didn't state the question clearly.

Comment: Indeed you "didn't state the question clearly", actually your own attempt clearly points at only one draw, not multiple draws. Note that even using several draws will not save you because $7$ divides no power of $5$. But... if you allow a random and almost surely finite number of draws, then things become very different.

Answer (score 0):

The basic idea is that if you draw twice there are $25$ possible outcomes.  Assign three to each output.  Otherwise, take another draw and (if you get here) you have $20$ possible results.  Assign two to each output and otherwise draw again.  Keep going until you succeed, which you will do with probability $1$.